# Calling a Web Service using WCF channel Factory.Is it possible?

Tags: wcf, channelfactory

In the project I am working on I need to call webservices (asmx).I would like to call them using wcf and using the channelfactory(No adding service Reference).

Some might have an interface(contract)many dont.

Is there an end to end example how to do it?

```
    var service=ChannelFactory<?>... How do I get the webserviceContract.
```

Surely this must be a common scenario to be able to call a webservice (asmx)

Thanks for your time

Comment: You could try creating an interface with the proper WCF decorations and the web service's methods signatures and use that plus basicHttpBinding.

Answer (score 1):

To expand upon my comment, you should be able to create an interface that has methods that match the web service methods in the asmx service.  For example:

**Web Service Methods**

```
string GetMessage()

void SendMessage(string message)

int AddNumbers(int x, int y)
```

**Service Contract**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IServiceName
{

    [OperationContract]
    string GetMessage();

    [OperationContract]
    void SendMessage(string message);

    [OperationContract]
    int AddNumbers(int x, int y)
}
```

**ChannelFactory**

```
ChannelFactory<IServiceName> serviceFactory =
          new ChannelFactory<IServiceName>(new BasicHttpBinding(), 
                             "http://www.services.com/Service.asmx");
```

Not 100% sure this will work, but it would be easy to try out.  Also, you'd probably want to set the namespace on the service contract (`[ServiceContract(Namespace = "somenamespace")]`) to match the legacy asmx service, otherwise the messages might not get processed.

Comment: thanks for your time and answer that would work ,I thought about it and I wanted to do the following:Temporarily add a webreference/serviceref it generates everthing then copy and remove the reference.My problem with this approach is that I would not work in my scenario.Users should be able to put just a "URL" and the methods will appear in a form and execute them.I need some sort of dynamic proxy for asmx.I need to generate those interfaces at runtime

Comment: If the services are different and not known ahead of time, then you'll need to do some sort of discovery on them (not even sure amsx supports that).  You might be better off using an Http API of some sort, like `WebClient` or similar.